# In a basic Shell Program in C, how to exit all processes associated with a parent?

Tags: c, shell, fork, exit, child-process

I am writing a basic shell program for a university assignment, and i need to test for when the user enters the string "exit". When this happens the program should quit.

I can test for this successfully, but if i have forked new processes that have dealt with an strerror in my program, i have to keep entering exit for however many active processes are running at that current time.

Is there a way of exiting all associated processes with a program under this condition?

Cheers.

Comment: Why are those processes hanging around waiting for input?  Shouldn't they have exited?  If you've got a record of all your direct children, you could have your parent shell send them death threats (SIGHUP, SIGTERM).  But it shouldn't be necessary.  Unless a shell is interactive, it should exit on error, or reaching the end of its script.

Comment: Yes, even with a true shell it is more than a bad idea to spawn commands that interact with stdin in the background… As stated by @JonathanLeffler whatever your shell should keep track of PIDs of background process, at least to get their returncode (as done by BASH for ex.).

Comment: If your shell does not support job control (which is very likely since you didn't mention it), you most definitely don't want / need to do this, and it's a strong hint that you're doing something wrong. When the shell forks to execute a user-typed command, it should wait for that process to terminate before accepting further input. This in turn implies that the user can't type `exit` until the previous command terminates. So you shouldn't have to worry about that at all. Of course, the command may have forked and exited immediately, but for a university assignment I wouldn't worry about that.

Answer (score 2):

As said in comments, you should not spawn interactive processes in the background (at least how your shell and your command will handle the only stdin?).

Also as a shell you should keep track of all spawned processes (in background) so that you are able to catch their return code, as done in sh/bash (at least). For exemple in bash:

```
> sleep 1 &
[1] 8215
>
(1 sec later)
[1]+  Terminated      sleep 1
```

So if you have the list of existing children you can send SIGINT/SIGKILL to all of them.

Whatever if you really want to be sure to kill everyone you should use process group (PG) killing. Using `kill()` function with PID=0 sends the kill signal to all processes in the same process group than you.
So you can start your shell by setting a new process group (to be sure to not kill something else), and this PG will be inherited by your children (appart if a child set a new PG of course).

This would looks like:

```
// at the begining of your main code
// try to get a new process group for me
x = setpgid(0,0);
if (x == -1) {
  perror("setpgid");
  exit(1);
}
(…)
// here you're about to exit from main, just kill
// all members of your group
kill(0, SIGINT);  // send an INT signal
kill(0, SIGKILL); // paranoid: if a child catch INT it will get a KILL

// now you can exit, but you're probably dead 'cause you
// also receive the SIGINT. If you want to survive you have to
// catch SIGINT, but you will not catch KILL whatever
```

If it is needed for you to survive the kill you may catch the signal using `signal()` or better `sigaction()` so that you will not be killed and so able to perform other before-exit actions.

Comment: `setpgid(2)` returns `int`, there's no need to perform casting in the `if`. Also, the way the question is phrased, it seems like multiple processes are concurrently trying to read from `stdin` (which is arguably undesirable), so doing this in the main shell program would not necessarily fix it, unless you're lucky enough to have that exact input line delivered to the shell process.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves: yes you're right. Confusion with `getpgid()`. I correct the post.

Comment: Note: for the "multiple processes are concurrently trying to read from stdin", as it is a nonsense (as you stated) I presumed a coherent code :)